# How to programatically redirect to error pages in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm running Nuxt 2, with a few custom things.

Everything related to the state of the application is handled in Vuex modules (32 of them, it's a rather complex app). When I want to fetch something, `fetch` is called from a view, which calls a mapped Vuex action, where the actual Axios call is wrapped in a `try...catch` block.

An action kind of looks like this after I remove the irrelevant details:

```js
async fetchVotes ({ commit }) {
  try {
    const response = await this.$secured.get('exampleapi.com/votes')
    const merged = jsonApiMerge(response.data.included, response.data.data)

    // processing

    commit(SET_VOTES_LIST, merged)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

It all works as expected.

Except I cannot redirect to the `error` layout - in the `catch` block I'd like to invoke something like `this.$error({ statusCode: err.code, message: err.message })` or similar. There doesn't seem to be anything on `this` that I could use.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Ended up doing `this.app.context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Vote not found' })`, which works, but it still feels wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In your catch you can redirect user to error page by

```
return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 500, message: 'your error message' })
```

your error.vue page, you can access it with an error prop like:

```
<p>{{ error.statusCode }}</p>
<p>{{ error.message }} </p>
```

i will work fine

Comment: There is no `$nuxt` available on `this` inside the store.